# RSA: Given the private key d, one can efficiently factor the modulus N = pq

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

Reading the article ["Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem"](http://www.ams.org/notices/199902/boneh.pdf) by Dan Boneh, I am trying to understand the proof of the *Fact 1* (Given the private key $d$, one can efficiently factor the modulus $N = pq$). Particularly this statement:

> We have $g^k = 1$ for every $g \in Z_N^∗$

that's obviously a mistake that meant to be:

> We have $g^k \equiv 1(\mod{N})$ for every $g \in Z_N^*$

where:

- $k = ed - 1$
- $N = pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime
- $(N,e)$ is a public RSA key
- $(N,d)$ is a private RSA key
- $Z_N^∗$ – multiplicative group (thanks @Matthew Towers)

I have problems understanding this claim. Where did it come from?

**My (wrong) reasoning.** According to the article:

> By definition of $d$ and $e$ we know that $k$ is a multiple of $\phi(N).$

That would make Euler's theorem applicable:
$g^{\phi(N)} \equiv 1 (\mod{N})$ for those values of $g \in Z_N^*$ which are coprime with $N$. But it wouldn't necessarily be true for $g = p \in Z_N^*$ and $g = q \in Z_N^*$, it seems, which are not coprime with $N = pq$... That's where I got lost.

**UPD.** My mistake was that I got $Z_N = \{0, ..., N-1\}$ (set of residues) mixed up with $Z_N^*$ (multiplicative group, or subset of $Z_N$ in which all numbers are coprime to $N$). Thanks for help!

Comment: What you've written is $Z_N$ not $Z_N^*$ which is the *multiplicative* group mod N - it doesn't contain p or q. It's also not a mistake to say $g^k=1$ - the exponentiation is happening in $Z_N^*$ not in the integers.

Comment: $Z_N^\ast$ has size $\phi(N)$, it's only the relatively prime elements. $Z_N$ is the set of *all* residues.

Comment: The first statement is not a mistake: it states an identity over $Z^\ast_N$ (so multiplication is automatically modulo $N$ as that is the operation in the set).

Comment: Thanks @MatthewTowers! That was indeed my incompetence.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $Z_N=\{0,1,\ldots,N-1\}$ is the set of *all* residues mod $N$ (it's a ring, with two operations, addition and multiplication modulo $N$) while $Z_N^\ast$ is the subset of co-prime (with $N$) residues (of size $\phi(N)$, under the operation multiplication modulo $N$ (it is a group). So $p,2p,q,2q, \ldots \notin Z_N^\ast$, contrary to what you seem to think.

You know that $e$ and $d$ are each other's inverses modulo $\phi(N)$ (this is how RSA works and how $e$ and $d$ are chosen, and it ensures that $x \to x^e \pmod{N}$ and $x \to x^d \pmod{N}$ are mutual inverses on $Z_N$), by Euler's theorem.

So $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(N)}$, or $ed-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{\phi(N)}$, so $k:= ed-1$ is a multiple of $\phi(N)=(p-1)(q-1)$, and so a multiple of the group order of $Z_N^\ast$ and hence the first statement holds.

Comment: Yeah, this was the part I understood. I was baffled by distinction between $Z_N$ and $Z_N^*$. But you comment made it clearer. Thanks!